# can i run React UI automated testing by clicking a button in my react app?

Tags: reactjs, testing, ui-automation, end-to-end

I want to automate some UI end-to-end tests by making the user click a button inside the react app, then the tests run and the user is able to see them in real-time.
is there a library that does that?

Answer (score 1):

**Ofc. You can do this with these.**

**[Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)**

**[Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/)**

Comment: can you please provide an example of a button being clicked to run the tests ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).